# append() missing 1 required positional argument: 'item_name'

Tags: python, class

I created a class called 'Inventory' and created a list that is meant to be made up of instances of a class called 'Item'. When creating a .append() method for the class 'Inventory' and then attempting to call it, I keep getting the kickback that I am missing a positional argument despite only one being required other than self.

'''

```
class Inventory:
    def __init__(self):
        self.items = []

    def append(self, item_name):
        item = Item(item_name)
        self.items.append(item)


    def print(self):
        for i in self.items:
            print(i.name)


class Item:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name



myInventory = Inventory

myInventory.append('Sword')
```

Comment: You need to actually create an instance of the class by doing `myInventory = Inventory()`. As of now, the `myInventory` variable points to the `Inventory` _class_

Answer (score 1):

What you did is

```py
myInventory = Inventory
```

You just copied the class
You had to instantiate the class

```py
myInventory = Inventory()
```

This will solve it

Comment: Thank you very much. I did not think to check that.